# MyEclipse Matisse switching view after any change

Tags: eclipse, view, myeclipse, matisse

I hope I'm not putting this in the wrong place; I don't where else to post it. I'm not sure if it's MyEclipse or the Matisse plugin, but after making ANY change, it switches from from the design view to the source view, it's driving me crazy. I didn't happen until my daughter (infant) pressed a random key combo. It's MyEclipse Blue 10, and I doubt it helps, but my OS is Windows 7 64 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what key combination could cause that but I suggest you try switching to a new workspace, import your project from the old workspace into the new one and see if that solves it. Or it might be something to do with [this issue](http://www.myeclipseide.com/PNphpBB2-viewtopic-t-28265.html) reported a couple of years ago. Otherwise, post on the [Myeclipse forums](http://www.myeclipseide.com/forums) for (hopefully) better support.

Comment: Thanks! That link did the trick (the second to last post). Sorry I can't vote up yet, my rep is still to low.